# Is this patent valid in USA or Australia?

Tags: usa

In reference to the patent: [EP1195548A2](https://www.google.com/patents/EP1195548A2)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "valid?" Are you wondering if it has expired? Or if the application (which has since become a patent) is from Australia or the United States?

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you for your prompt response. I am trying to ascertain if this product has had either an application made , or a patent is current in USA or Australia.  Regards Adam

Comment: The application number (which was eventually granted) is for the European Union, and from what I see, it never touched the United States or Australia, as a patent at least.

Answer (score 2):

Patents are territorial rights  and European patent will have no effect on US and Australia. Now based on patent family it can be said that no equivalent patent was filed in US or AU.

**Finding Patent Families**

Search patent number in

http://worldwide.espacenet.com/?locale=en_EP

Find your patent in result list  and locate family member.

> An INPADOC patent family is defined as comprising all the documents
>   sharing directly or indirectly (e.g. via a third document) at least
>   one priority. This includes all the patent documents resulting from a
>   patent application submitted as a first filing with a patent office
>   and from the same patent application filed within the priority year
>   with a patent office in any other country. In Espacenet these can be
>   found by selecting INPADOC patent family from the left-hand sidebar in
>   the bibliographic data view.

[image]