# Author/Inventor contact

Tags: ownership

In reference to the patent: [CA2699138A1](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2699138A1)

I have fibromyalgia and am very intrigued by this patent and the studies/research it is built upon. What has ever happened to this patent? Is there a way to get hold of the author/inventor Paul Jenkins to learn more (example about clinical trials, or to just communicate).

Answer (score 0):

For finding applicant or inventor information please follow these procedures

1. Find Family members of patent: [Link](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/12153/11895)
2. Find US patent member
3. Find Inventors or attorney address [Link](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/5351/11895)