# U.S. patent for mobile app

Tags: mobile

We're working on a mobile app and discovered that a competitor has an active U.S. patent on the same idea and workflow. However, we are in the UK.

- Does the U.S. patent apply to our works?
- Are we allowed to distribute our app in international App Stores?
- Must we exclude the U.S. from the store markets?

**Edit:** *Some research shows that there is a WIPO patent, too.*

Comment: Take the "U.S." in "active U.S. patent" as a clue as to the scope / limit of the monopoly rights ;-)

Comment: @arober11 "Must we exclude the U.S. from the store markets that have our app listed?"

Comment: If you suspect you'll infringe a VALID US patent go seek legal advice.

Comment: Added a note that there is an international application, too. What consequences does it have?

Comment: @Jublo check for family patents

Comment: @Pushpak What are family patents, and where to check?

Comment: Please check http://patents.stackexchange.com/a/12153/11895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tricky area legally. I don't think your scenario would even get to legal action, however. It's much more likely that the patent holder would complain to the app store. The most likely outcome of such a complaint is that your app would be summarily delisted, at least from U.S. market, as the app store has little incentive to fight on your behalf and likely incurs liability itself if based in the U.S.

If you want to investigate the legal aspects, here's a link to a relevant article:

http://jolt.richmond.edu/v14i1/article1.pdf