# What countries is this patent effective US5710377 A

Tags: international, pct, jurisdiction, us5710377

In reference to the patent: [US5710377](https://www.google.com/patents/US5710377)

In what countries is patent US5710377A effective/protected currently?

Comment: FYI it was not filed outside US.

Comment: It is a US patent but is very likely expired.

Answer (score 1):

This is a US patent.  You can tell by the publication numbers:

> **US**08540616 
>   **US**5710377A

both of which begin with the letters "US".

The patent would be expired as of 2015, since it was filed in 1995.  (The grant was in 1998, but the period of protection extends retroactively from the date of first filing.

I didn't see any links to an international application, so the protection would have been in the US exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

extension of duplicate [Is this patent valid in USA or Australia?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/12132/11895) ; A person need to cross-check kind codes of patents for granted patent.

Limitation:- EPO or INPADOC database might have inherent limitation e.g. non avalability or software errors. try more with inventor and applicant search.

Answer (score -1):

its already expired so its not going to protect anywhere

Comment: This is actually a useful answer. If you explained how you determined this, it would strengthen the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This patent belongs to US (United States)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! Technically, your answer is correct - however, it is not of much use for anyone. Could you explain how you know that so future readers can figure it out for themself for other patents? And the person asking the question seems to know little about the PCT system, so including the information that, while **this** patent is for the US, there might be other family members in other countries and how to find them would certainly help.