# What is the current status of US6493686?

Tags: software, us6493686

It says lapsed for US6493686, but I do not understand why. Is this information up to date?

How can I determine the reason for this patent having lapsed, for example if it was abandoned for non-payment, where could I find that out?

Comment: yes it lapsed...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you determine a patent's expiration date?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/how-do-you-determine-a-patents-expiration-date)

Comment: @Pushpak, please tell me if this is because of not being paid or by certain number of years.  Also please tell me if the "also published as" will lapse by date next year in July due to 20yr rule.  Thank you.

Comment: Using method to locate information on USPTO PAIR a person can find out status as :- Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR 1.362; but you should know about family patent US5946673

Answer (score 0):

USPTO PAIR can be found at:- http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

put the patent number and select the corresponding radio button

review the information:-

For example your patent document was expired due to non payment, but its related patent application also called parent application was found to be active. therefore you should know about family patent US5946673;

Earlier an answer has been made to know about family patents See [Find family memeber](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/12153/11895)

[image]