# Is WO and US patents valid in EU?

Tags: european, valid

I read allot of the answers to your most question on this website and these where really helpful in getting a general idea of the patent laws.

Hope that someone can help me out with the following question.
I want to sell the following product in EU: Car Seat Gap Filler.
On this item there is a patent WO_2008_144261_A1 and the original product is patented in the US(US20080283565 A1).

The biggest question are we allowed to sell this product in the EU and are we not braking the patent with the "Drop Stop" product that is connected to the patent.
Product that we like to sell is sold on Amazon but the delivery happens out of China and also this not answered the question: are we braking laws in selling in EU.

Comment: i urge you to remove image and limit your question to said patent application validity only. such disclosures of goods and evaluation should be made to attorney and not on online forums.

Comment: Patents are territorial rights (country specific) first find out if family patent was filed in EU; e.g. US patent valid in US only. here is link to find family member http://patents.stackexchange.com/a/12153/11895

Answer (score 1):

The patent in question was granted in the US only:
https://patents.google.com/patent/US8267291B2/en

The same patent was not filed in the European Patent Office (EPO) or any other office or country, and too much time has elapsed to do so.

Therefore, the only risk of infringement is within the US market.

Comment: Factually correct answer, but it would be stronger if you teach how you determined there were no EPO filings (links, steps, etc.)